# MySQL database design for custom meta key => value queries

Tags: mysql, database-design, metadata, key-value

I am making a product database for my website. I currently have:

Products Table: Product ID, Product name, Price

Product_meta Table: Pmeta_id, Product ID, metaKey, metaValue

I basically want it so I can query a product by specifying the meta key and either put a key=>value pair to it, or get the value by the key.

I believe Wordpress has a similar approach but am not quite sure how to go about making the functions to get the data. I assume it will involve table joins???

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Product_meta AS M
LEFT OUTER JOIN Products AS P ON ( P.Product_ID = M.Product_ID )
WHERE M.metaKey = ...
```

Or turn it around if the Products table is leading:

```
SELECT * FROM Products AS P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product_meta AS M ON ( P.Product_ID = M.Product_ID )
WHERE M.metaKey = ...
```

You can also change `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` when you only want to display the records that are both in the Products table and in the Product_meta table

If you want to have more than one value in the `WHERE` clause then use this query:

```
... WHERE M.metaKey IN (..,..,..)
```

Make sure your data is comma seperated

Answer (score 1):

It will invlovle `JOIN`'s but more important is that, you will need to *pivot* all the rows so that you have those meta keys as columns rather than rows. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  p.productid, 
  p.productname, 
  p.price,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.metaname = 'Type' THEN pm.metavalue END) AS 'Type',
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.metaname = 'Size' THEN pm.metavalue END) AS 'Size',
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.metaname = 'Quantity' THEN pm.metavalue END) AS 'Quantity'
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN product_meta pm ON p.productID = pm.productid
INNER JOIN metakeys m ON pm.metakey = m.metakey
GROUP BY p.productid, 
         p.productname, 
         p.price;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19cdf/5)

---

You can also do this dynamically for all the keys you have, instead of manually write them:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(m.metaName = ''',
      m.metaName, ''', pm.metavalue, NULL)) AS ',
      m.metaName )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN product_meta pm ON p.productID = pm.productid
INNER JOIN metakeys m ON pm.metakey = m.metakey
;



SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.productid, p.productname,',
                  'p.price, ', @sql,
                  ' FROM products p  ',
                  ' INNER JOIN product_meta pm ON p.productID = pm.productid ',
                  ' INNER JOIN metakeys m ON pm.metakey = m.metakey ',
                  ' GROUP BY p.productid, p.productname, p.price; ');
PREPARE stmt 
FROM @sql; 

EXECUTE stmt;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19cdf/11)